# Dell WD15 Dock monitors not working with HP Envy x360

Tags: dell, hp, monitor, dock

So I recently installed Ubuntu 21.04 as dual boot with Windows 10 on my HP Envy x360 Laptop. It has AMD Ryzen 7 4000 Series CPU with onboard AMD Radeon Graphics.

When I plug this in via USB-C to my Dell WD15 dock, All peripherals work and ethernet works perfectly. However neither of my 2 Dell U2419H monitors are recognised so I'm forced to use the built in laptop display which of course impacts productivity a lot. xrandr does not see the monitors at all.

The dock and monitors work perfectly when I boot into windows 10 on the same machine so I'm confident that the USB-C port supports Display Port output. Thinking this is a software issue but cannot seem to find the answer through trawling to forums.

Has anyone found a working solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Updating this for anyone else searching for the answer...

After a lot of messing about, it turns out this was not working due to secure boot being enabled on my machine.

Simply going in the BIOS and disabling Secure Boot fixed the issue for me.